# How to map items to pool map results in python

Tags: python

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
def add (x):
    return x + 2

if __name__ == '__main__':
    x = [('a', 1) ,('b', 2) ,('c', 3), ('d', 4)]
    y = list ()
    for items, values in x:
        y.append(values)
    p = Pool(5)
    response = p.map(add, y)
    print(response)
    p.close()
```

In above case I want to map results [3, 4, 5, 6] to ['a', 'b','c','d']
and it should be [('a', 3) ,('b', 3) ,('c', 5), ('d', 6)]

Note: I cant modify add function

Comment: You can use a list comprehension with `zip`: `[(pair[0], result) for pair, result in zip(x, response)]`

Answer (score 0):

As @alkasm mentioned, you can use list comprehension and `zip` to link you input list to the result list. You can also use list comprehension to create the `y` list.

Try this code:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
def add (x):
    return x + 2

if __name__ == '__main__':
    x = [('a', 1) ,('b', 2) ,('c', 3), ('d', 4)]
    y = [e[1] for e in x]  # 1,2,3,4

    p = Pool(5)
    response = p.map(add, y)
    res = list(zip([e[0] for e in x], response))
    print(res)
    p.close()
```

Output

```
[('a', 3), ('b', 4), ('c', 5), ('d', 6)]
```